# Difference between these Python structures

Tags: python, arrays, list, set

What's the difference between:

```
things = []

things = {}

things = set()
```

I tried googling but it's difficult to Google for constructs like these with only brackets to identify them without knowing their actual names.

There's also (element1, element2) that I've seen passed as an argument to a function but I don't know what Python interprets it as.

Comment: They're called `list`, `dict`, and `set`. *To the Google-mobile!*

Comment: Try the `type` function on these *things*.

Comment: [Python Programming/Sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sequences)

Comment: where ever you found those symbol, will surely explained what they are, and you may not need to ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are

1. [list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list)
2. [dict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mapping-types-dict)
3. [set](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)

Welcome to Python!

Oh, I forgot to say, if you are new too Python (and even in not) I recommend that you look into [IPython](http://ipython.org/).

And when ever you don't know anything in python just do:

```
help(thing)
```

e.g

```
help([]) # will show this ...
Help on list object:

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
 |
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ world, they are

- `list [] = std::vector`
- `set = std::set`
- `dict {} = std::map`